# Lightning "change" event doesn't fire in aura:Iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, platform-bug, lightning-events, onchange, aura-iteration

I am passing an Object to my component and iterate through it's child records.
To handle changes I added the Lightning change handler.

(I made `data` an array, so I can set a default for demo purposes, plain objects somehow didn't work for me)

```
<aura:attribute name="data" type="Object[]" default="[{values:[123, 456, 789]}]"/>

<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.data}" action="{!c.foo}"/>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.data[0].values}" var="value">
    <ui:inputNumber value="{!value}" />
</aura:iteration>
```

Controller

```
foo: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    console.error(cmp.get("v.data"));
},
```

Changes are written to data, but won't trigger the change event.

Only if I do this, the change event will be fired:

```
<ui:inputNumber value="{!v.data[0].values[0]}" />
<ui:inputNumber value="{!v.data[0].values[1]}" />
```

These exact lines do also work within any loop, so it's not that aura:iteration would block these events or something.

It shouldn't be like that, right? is this behavior documented anywhere? is there any best practice? I could add an onchange listener to every element in the loop, but hey it's lightnings job, not mine ;)

Comment: Just opened an issue for this: https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/issues/128

Comment: I've just run into this same bug. I can't believe this hasn't been addressed by SF. This is madness.